# PHP date not getting the correct time

Tags: php

I have an infuriating issue with my php date function in which it gets the wrong time.

I am using ubuntu 12.04LTS and php verion 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13

My system time is correct:

```
    #sudo hwclock --debug
    hwclock from util-linux 2.20.1
    Using /dev interface to clock.
    Last drift adjustment done at 1409943046 seconds after 1969
    Last calibration done at 1409943046 seconds after 1969
    Hardware clock is on UTC time
    Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
    Waiting for clock tick...
    ...got clock tick
    Time read from Hardware Clock: 2014/09/05 20:11:17
    Hw clock time : 2014/09/05 20:11:17 = 1409947877 seconds since 1969
    Fri 05 Sep 2014 21:11:17 BST  -0.550945 seconds
#date
Fri Sep  5 21:12:23 BST 2014
```

However if I use date i get this:

```
TIME STAMP: 1409944442
DATE (M/D/Y @ h:m:s): 09 / 05 / 14 @ 7:14:02pm UTC
```

In my php code I have this:
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
The current time is 2 hours ahead of this. If does detect when I do `date('I')` that daylight saving is TRUE but this only takes me to 8pm and I still need an extra hour.

I have not changed my php.ini I do have the ntp service running if and it is the correct time (not sure if that info is needed?)

Thanks for any help

Comment: They're two different timezones. You need to convert your timestamp from UTC into the current timezone for your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time()` function

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
   echo "UTC:".time();
   date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki");
   echo "Europe/Helsinki:".time();

   $now = time()+ (24 * 60 * 60);
   echo $now;
?>
```

Which ever way you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see what the problem is. Your two timestamps are obviously taken at different times, and the timestrings you're getting from them ARE identical, when you factor that that difference:

```
hwclock: 1409947877 -> 2014/09/05 20:11:17
date   : 1409944442 -> 2014/09/05 19:14:02
------------------
 diff  :       3435 seconds

 20:11:17 - 19:14:02 = 3435 seconds
```

If it was a timezone issue, then your differences would be a nice round multiple of 3600 (1 hour). not 0.954166666 hours.

Answer (score 0):

`now()` is an in-built function in `MySQl database`. If you are trying to get time stamp then you can use PHP `time()` as answered above OR make the settings in the database you are using.